# Doc2Vec: strange results with model.docvecs.most_similar

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I try to train model to get sentence similarity (In my case names of some organization)

I use to train model

```
names_tok = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(name.lower()), tags=[str(i)])
                        for (i, name) in enumerate(names)]

# train model
max_epochs = 50
vec_size = 50
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha,
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                dm=1)
```

And I get results with

```
name = word_tokenize(name.lower())
infer_v = model.infer_vector(name)
results = model.docvecs.most_similar([infer_v]))
```

And it returns strange results for all tests. I've already tried to use example from train data and I haven't got it with similarity. For example `Филип Моррис Продактс С.А.` I get next results

```
Найк Инноувейт С.В.: 0.9336682558059692

СОСЬЕТЕ ДЕ ПРОДЮИ НЕСТЛЕ С.А.: 0.9370058178901672

Юнилевер Н.В.: 0.9347286224365234

Мерк Шарп и Доум Корп.: 0.9339677095413208
```

And I can't understand Why I get this.
I have 180 000 examples of train data.
How can I improve results of my model?

Comment: You'll have to show your code that trains the model, and then the code that retrieves similar results from a query. (There are many common errors in those steps.) Also, `Doc2Vec` works best on natural-language documents of dozens to hundreds (or thousands) of words. Using it on 'names' of just 2-5 tokens *might* work, if there are still varied levels-of-correlation between tokens, but isn't where the algorithm necessarily shines.

Comment: @gojomo I've updated my question and add code with getting similarities

Comment: @gojomo Is there another way to get most similar names to request from all data?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look your similarity code has any obvious errors, but note that since you didn't supply an `epochs` parameter on model-creation, it will be internally configured to use just 5 passes on inference. (Usual Doc2Vec work uses 10-20 or more, and inference can sometimes benefit from more, especially for smaller texts.)

Also, your question doesn't show your training code - and many online examples include egregious errors in the handling of `epochs` and `alpha`.

I can't read your name texts – which I'm guessing is Russian, and perhaps company names? But as in my comment, `Doc2Vec` really works best with longer texts. I'd only expect it be useful for smaller texts if there are usefully varied token-to-token correlations, that also reflect the kind of "similarity" you're seeking.

But it's not clear what kind of similarity you're seeking. If it's purely superficial/morphological, you might analyze the names by subtoken fragments - character n-grams - instead of space-delimited words. If it's a more subtle similarity-of-purpose, or industry, or public perception, then metadata other than the literal names might be more useful, such as:

- uses of the names in natural-language contexts
- the entities' self-descriptions, in free-form or categorized into controlled-taxonomies
- 3rd party descriptions of the entities

Retaining even tokens that appear just once – `min_count=1` – can also weaken word-vectors/doc-vectors, since there's little generalizable meaning that can be learned from probably-idiosyncratic single occurrences, but the aggregate appearance of all those rare words injects noisy interference into the training of other surrounding more-common words. For large natural-language corpuses, with plenty of examples of relevant word-tokens, often increasing `min_count` can improve model quality.